# Put parameters for different functions inside an array in C++?

Tags: c++

So in Python I can do something like

```
def f1(a, b):
    print("sum", a + b)

def f2(str1, str2):
    print("min len str", min(len(str1), len(str2)))

def f3(a,b,c,d):
    print("product", a*b*c*d)

functions = [f1, f2, f3]
params = [(1,2),('test str', 'testdtr'), (1,2,4,3)]
for i in range(len(functions)):
    functions[i](*(params[i]))
```

Output:

```
sum 3
min len str 7
product 24
```

Is there a way to achieve this in C++?

Comment: In C++, you are looking for `std::vector`.  The containers in C++ are homogenous, they only operate on one type.  You could use an all encompassing struct for that type.  Another trick is to use a `string` and convert the data into a single string.

Comment: In C++, you could use `template`s.  A `template` allows containers or functions to have the same functionality applied to different data types.  Remember, Python is a different language, it is type agnostic (to the reader) for many things; C++ is not.

Comment: Basically, no; don't try to imitate other languages` syntax.

Comment: Is having an iterable container a hard requirement? Something like `std::tuple functions { f1, f2, f3 }; some_type params ...;` would be more idiomatic C++

Comment: Just store `std::function` with no parameters, and assign lambdas to them.

Comment: @Caleth not really, I just thought it would be convenient in certain cases e.g. starting a bunch of threads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, data must be typed. This makes the syntax heavier but allows control during the compilation phase.
To store entities of different types, the container to use is the `tuple`.

To traverse the `tuple`, we cannot use the `for`. The iterations are made with the `index_sequence` object (to make indices), and a pack expansion (to apply each indice).
To call functions using `tuple` in place of parameters, we need `apply()`.
We can define the iteration in place using a lambda template immediately instantiated and called (`[]<>(){}()`).

```cpp
import  std;

auto  f1( double a, double b ) {
   endl( std::cout << "sum " << a + b);
}
auto   f2( std::string_view str1, std::string_view str2 ) {
   endl( std::cout << "min len str " << std::min(size(str1),size(str2)) );
}
auto  f3( double a, double b, double c, double d ) {
   endl( std::cout << "product " << a * b * c * d );
}

int  main() {
   auto functions = std::tuple{ f1,f2,f3 };
   auto params = std::tuple{
         std::tuple{1,2},
         std::tuple{"test str", "testdtr"},
         std::tuple{1,2,4,3}
      };

   [&]<size_t...I>( std::index_sequence<I...> ){
         (std::apply( std::get<I>(functions), std::get<I>(params) ), ...);
      }( std::make_index_sequence<3>{} );
}
```

Use `std::tuple{1,2,3},` in place of `std::tuple{1,2},` and the compilation fails. All is checked at **compilation time**.

Answer (score 2):

Since C++ is strongly typed, it is not as flexible as Python is for duck typing functions to their arguments (by applying a tuple).

Here's an example of doing it that most closely matches your Python code.  It has considerably more boilerplate to glue things together, and a lot more groveling to extricate the function and apply the tuple as arguments.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

using std::apply;
using std::cout;
using std::get;
using std::literals::string_literals::operator""s;
using std::make_tuple;
using std::min;
using std::size_t;
using std::string;
using std::tuple;
using std::variant;
using std::vector;

namespace {

void f1(int a, int b) {
    cout << "sum " << (a + b) << "\n";
}

void f2(string const& str1, string const& str2) {
    cout << "min len str " << min(str1.size(), str2.size()) << "\n";
}

void f3(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    cout << "product " << (a * b * c * d) << "\n";
}

using fn_var = variant< decltype(&f1), decltype(&f2), decltype(&f3) >;
using arg_var = variant< tuple<int, int>, tuple<string, string>, tuple<int, int, int, int> >;
using vec_fn = vector<fn_var>;
using vec_arg = vector<arg_var>;

template <typename... Ts>
struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
// Explicit deduction guide. I'm on C++17, not needed for C++20.
template <typename... Ts>
overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

} // anon

int main() {
    vec_fn functions{ &f1, &f2, &f3 };
    vec_arg params{ make_tuple(1, 2), make_tuple("test str"s, "testdtr"s), make_tuple(1, 2, 3, 4) };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < functions.size(); ++i) {
        auto&& f = functions[i];
        auto&& a = params[i];

        visit(overloaded{
            [&](decltype(&f1) fn) { apply(fn, get<0>(a)); },
            [&](decltype(&f2) fn) { apply(fn, get<1>(a)); },
            [&](decltype(&f3) fn) { apply(fn, get<2>(a)); },
        }, f);
    }
}
```

> That looks really complex...

Agreed.  But I was trying to mimic as closely as possible what your Python code is doing.

Ted's alternative is much less fussy, and is more idiomatic C++.

> so this is basically creating a struct that inherits from all 3 lambda functions, with each lambda handing a different function?

Correct.  The `overloaded` is a set of lambdas, which are selected by the one that has the matching argument type, which is effectly based on the function signature.

> Also would you mind explaining what `get<0>(a)` is doing (if I understand correctly it basically means extracting the 1st element from a)?

The `variant` type can hold one type from a set of types.  The `variant`'s [`std::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get) retrieves the that type by position from that variant set (counting in the order specified).  So `get<0>(a)` retrieves the `tuple<int, int>`, or `throw`s if that type is not the currently held value.

Comment: Thanks! That looks reaally complex... so this is basically creating a struct that inherits from all 3 lambda functions, with each lambda handing a different function? Also would you mind explaining what `get<0>(a)` is doing (if I understand correctly it basically means extracting the 1st element from `a`)?

Answer (score 1):

Since the functions have different signatures, you can't store them directly in the same array. You could however wrap both the functions and their arguments in functor objects that *do* have the same signature, like lambdas.

A possible solution could then look like this:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void f1(int a, int b) { std::cout << "sum" << (a + b) << '\n'; }

void f2(std::string str1, std::string str2) {
    std::cout << "min len str" << std::min(str1.size(), str2.size()) << '\n';
}

void f3(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    std::cout << "product" << (a * b * c * d) << '\n';
}

int main() {
    using func = void (*)();
    func functions[] = {
        [] { f1(1, 2); },
        [] { f2("test str", "testdtr"); },
        [] { f3(1, 2, 4, 3); },
    };
    for (auto& f : functions) {
        f();
    }
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't separate the functions array from the parameters array!

Comment: @PeteBecker Correct. It packs them together. For a different set of parameters, one would have to create a different set of wrappers if this solution is used.